# Is there are something like Python's 'pass' statement in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I am a newer to Nim programing language. when I use Python, I can use the 'pass' to skip the defination detail of a function and class.

```py
def foo():
    pass # skip detail

class Bar():
    pass
```

Is there are something like this in Nim?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`discard` does the same in Nim:

```
proc foo =
  discard # skip detail

type Bar = object
```

For objects it's not even necessary, but possible, to specify `discard`